# OpenSSL 3.0 command fail to setting cipher

Tags: openssl, blowfish

Starting with OpenSSL 3.0 the following command (which work on OpenSSL 1.1)

```
openssl bf-cbc -d -nopad -bufsize 2048 -K 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F -iv 0001020304050607 < enc
```

now fail with

> Error setting cipher BF-CBC
> 40CCA0B4217F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (BF-CBC : 13), Properties ()

Looking at [evp_fetch.c:349](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/openssl-3.0/crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c#L349) I think I got a NULL method

But the `-help` screen don't provide anything related to specify a method

```
Usage: bf-cbc [options]

General options:
 -help               Display this summary
 -list               List ciphers
 -ciphers            Alias for -list
 -e                  Encrypt
 -d                  Decrypt
 -p                  Print the iv/key
 -P                  Print the iv/key and exit
 -engine val         Use engine, possibly a hardware device

Input options:
 -in infile          Input file
 -k val              Passphrase
 -kfile infile       Read passphrase from file

Output options:
 -out outfile        Output file
 -pass val           Passphrase source
 -v                  Verbose output
 -a                  Base64 encode/decode, depending on encryption flag
 -base64             Same as option -a
 -A                  Used with -[base64|a] to specify base64 buffer as a single line

Encryption options:
 -nopad              Disable standard block padding
 -salt               Use salt in the KDF (default)
 -nosalt             Do not use salt in the KDF
 -debug              Print debug info
 -bufsize val        Buffer size
 -K val              Raw key, in hex
 -S val              Salt, in hex
 -iv val             IV in hex
 -md val             Use specified digest to create a key from the passphrase
 -iter +int          Specify the iteration count and force use of PBKDF2
 -pbkdf2             Use password-based key derivation function 2
 -none               Don't encrypt
 -z                  Compress or decompress encrypted data using zlib
 -*                  Any supported cipher

Random state options:
 -rand val           Load the given file(s) into the random number generator
 -writerand outfile  Write random data to the specified file

Provider options:
 -provider-path val  Provider load path (must be before 'provider' argument if required)
 -provider val       Provider to load (can be specified multiple times)
 -propquery val      Property query used when fetching algorithms
```

According to the wiki, the 1.1 -> 3.0 migration shall be backward compatible
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Upgrading_to_OpenSSL_3.0_from_OpenSSL_1.1.1

Also, the `-debug` flags show that the OpenSSL3.0 cannot even create a cypher

```
Error setting cipher BF-CBC
407C4A7BB27F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (BF-CBC : 13), Properties ()
BIO[0x55a2269514d0]: Free - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55a2269515a0]: Free - FILE pointer
```

while OpenSSL 1.1 can

```
BIO[0x55d62a675ff0]: ctrl(6) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a675ff0]: ctrl return 0
BIO[0x55d62a673990]: ctrl return 0
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl(10) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl return 0
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl(2) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl return 0
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: read(0,2048) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: read return 2048
BIO[0x55d62a673990]: write(0,2048) - cipher
BIO[0x55d62a675ff0]: write(0,2048) - FILE pointer
...
BIO[0x55d62a675ff0]: write return 2048
BIO[0x55d62a673990]: write return 2048
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl(10) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl return 0
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl(2) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: ctrl return 0
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: read(0,2048) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: read return 0
BIO[0x55d62a673990]: ctrl(11) - cipher
BIO[0x55d62a675ff0]: ctrl(11) - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a675ff0]: ctrl return 1
BIO[0x55d62a673990]: ctrl return 1
BIO[0x55d62a670ab0]: Free - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a675ff0]: Free - FILE pointer
BIO[0x55d62a673990]: Free - cipher
```

What missing argument shall I provide to make this new "method" context work ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One of the key differences between OpenSSL 3.0 and earlier versions is that crypto algorithms are now supplied through "providers". Most commonly used ciphers are available in the "default" provider - which gets loaded by default. You are trying to use the blowfish cipher. That cipher is implemented in the "legacy" OpenSSL 3.0 provider:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man7/OSSL_PROVIDER-legacy.html

The legacy provider does not get loaded by default. You can load it explicitly by adding `-provider legacy -provider default` onto your command line, i.e.

```bash
openssl bf-cbc -d -nopad -bufsize 2048 -K 000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F -iv 0001020304050607 -provider legacy -provider default < enc
```