# Apache/PHP Installing cypher for openssl() - missed in openssl_get_cipher_methods

Tags: php, openssl

I just migrated to PHP 8.1 from a very old server.
Now I have the problem that openssl_encrypt returns false or an empty string as it doesnt' know BF-ECB engine what worked before on older server.

The command openssl_get_cipher_methods verifies this, no BF-ECB available.
On the old server is OpenSSL1.1 on the new 3.0.

Can anyone help what do I need to install or tell my administrator?

Answer (score 3):

See this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72449784/892493) by Matt Caswell with for the explanation why this is happening and how to fix it. I had the same issue after upgrading to PHP 8.1, and found that `bf-cbc` was not available in OpenSSL 3.0 by default.

In OpenSSL 3.0, Blowfish became a legacy cipher and is not loaded by default. When PHP tries to use that cipher for encryption it fails since it is not loaded and available for use.

To make this work from PHP, the OpenSSL configuration file needs to be updated to enable legacy ciphers. Here are the steps to fix it.

Look for the "Openssl default config" value in [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/phpinfo). The location will vary by platform. On a Debian box, it was `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf`. If there is no value for this setting, you'll need to find it or create a new openssl configuration file and set it in php.ini.

[image: php openssl configuration]

Next, open `openssl.cnf` in a text editor and find the settings section `[provider_sect]`. Below the line `default = default_sect`, add a line with `legacy = legacy_sect`.

Finally, find the section `[default_sect]` and add this new section after it:

```
[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

With the comments removed, part of the config file should look similar to:

```
[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

# List of providers to load
[provider_sect]
default = default_sect
legacy = legacy_sect

[default_sect]
activate = 1

[legacy_sect]
activate = 1
```

Once the openssl configuration file is updated to load the legacy provider, Blowfish ciphers should now work and appear in the list of ciphers returned by `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` (sorted alphabetically).

Answer (score -1):

I got bf-ecb when calling openssl_get_cipher_methods(), try doing

```
<?php
openssl_get_cipher_methods()[61]; // 'bf-ecb'
?>
```

I did the following to make it work:

```
<?php
$cipher = openssl_get_cipher_methods()[61];
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher); // iv_length = 0;

$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4);

if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, "", $tag); // note that I've passed $iv = "" in order to get the &$tag;
    echo "$ciphertext" . PHP_EOL;
    echo bin2hex($ciphertext) . PHP_EOL;
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, "", $tag); // $iv = "" again;
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

I built it over the documentation from openssl_encrypt();
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.openssl-encrypt.php